# JavaScript: Reference of `forEach` is not called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was using Node 13.12.0.
Consider the following code snippet:

```js
const A = function () {
    this.someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    this.forEach = this.someArray.forEach;
}

const a = new A();
a.forEach(item => console.log(item)); // should print the content of the array, but got nothing
```

When running the code above, no output was given nor any error was thrown. When putting a breakpoint inside the `forEach` callback, the breakpoint was not triggered.

But the code below does yield expected output:

```js
const A = function () {
    this.doSomething = () => {
        console.log('hello');
    };
};

const B = function () {
    this.a = new A();

    this.doSomething = this.a.doSomething;
};

const b = new B();
b.doSomething(); // prints 'hello'
```

I have checked other questions about `forEach` but it seems that none of them relates to this question.
Is there any explaination why they behave differently?

I have suspected that it might because `this` was different when called from different objects. But a quick check in a debugger turned out it was the same.

I also figured out that `forEach` is a native function. Does this have something to do with the question?

Comment: You're losing the context when you just assign `forEach` as a function reference. If you want to do that, you need `this.forEach = this.someArray.forEach.bind(this.someArray)`

Comment: I guess not a perfect match but it does explain what's wrong in situations similar to the one in the question as well as how to handle those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind to the array `someArray` so that when you invoke the `forEach` it refers to `someArray` while iterating, since you have taken out the `forEach` from the `someArray`:

```js
const A = function () {
    this.someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    //Binds the this context to this.someArray
    this.forEach = this.someArray.forEach.bind(this.someArray);
    // This is also equivalent
    //this.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach.bind(this.someArray);
}

const a = new A();
a.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

You can also use an arrow function to preserve the `this` context from the lexical scope. The `this` from the lexical scope can be passed as the second argument to the `forEach`:

```js
const A = function() {
  this.someArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  //Using Arrow functions
  this.forEach = callback => this.someArray.forEach(callback, this)
}

const a = new A();
a.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're detaching the `forEach` method from its array, which causes `this` to point to the `a` instance instead of `this.someArray` when `s.forEach` is invoked.

I'd expect it to work if you changed it to:

```js
this.forEach = (...args) => this.someArray.forEach(...args);
```

or if you changed it to:

```js
this.forEach = this.someArray.forEach.bind(this.someArray);
```